# How to hide/display rows in datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to hide/display certain rows based on data from a hidden column. my table structure looks like:

```
<table id="agent_search" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>Agent ID</th>
        <th>Agent Name</th>
        <th>ID Number</th>
        <th>Mobile Number</th>
        <th>Team Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I am trying to hide/show records based on the `Status` column, using a checkbox. If the status == `DEREGISTERED` I want to exclude it from the table (unchecked checkbox).

I adapted my code from what was done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/afarber/EtyUZ/):

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    // does not run this
    console.log("GOTHRERE"); 
    if ('agent_search' == oSettings.nTable.id) {
        // console.dir(oSettings);
        console.dir(aData);

        var dereg = aData[5];
        console.log(dereg);
        if (dereg == "DEACTIVATED"){
                return $('#toggle_deregistred').is(':checked');
        } else {
            return $('#toggle_deregistred').is(':not:checked');
        }
    } 

    return true;
});
```

I have tried using `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering` witch is used for [custom filtering](http://www.datatables.net/development/filtering), only to find that I can not do it. It was once possible in previous versions of dataTables as in [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/19593/datatables-update-breaks-fn-datatableext-afnfiltering-simple-test-case-attached) case , but as it turns out it was a [bug](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/commit/964addd0) that allowed it to be possible `:|`.

Is there a way that I can filter out rows based on if their `Status` with the use of a checkbox? or is there something in the `api` I can use that I have over looked?

**UPDATE:**

I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kc56p47L/1/) in which it is working, how ever in the process of adapting my code to put it in jsfiddle, I noticed that it is `bServerSide` that is causing the `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering` not to work. Is there a work around or another way to user Server-side processing?

Comment: You could add a DEREGISTERED class to your tablerows at the time you are creating them from your data, and add an event listener to the checkbox. When the checkbox is changed, call the hide() method on the offending table row. Call show() when you want to show the table row again. Why bother with custom filtering when you can do it the way that's easier for everyone to read? :)

Comment: @imdabestmanideedeet Thanks for your suggestion. It is a good idea, but the problem comes in when I start searching for the records. It reDraws the table in order to display only the relevant records, and as result it shows the records with status `DEREGISTERED` again. any suggestions?

Comment: Could you put your own code in a JSFiddle page? That would make it easier for everyone to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Updated question with jsfiddle...

Comment: There are no rows with a "DEREGISTERED" value, there's only one row with "DEACTIVATED". I assume you want the checkbox to hide all rows that have the class "DEACTIVATED" if it's unchecked, and show those rows when it's checked. Your original code already seems to do this in the fiddle. However, I added a method that specifically hides and shows the rows: http://jsfiddle.net/kc56p47L/7/

Comment: Sorry about that, my mistake... Your added method does not work, because `fnDraw()` redraws the table without consideration for what you 'manually' changed. The jsfiddle works as I had it, but when I add `"bServerSide": true` it does not work.. I can not demonstrate this in jsfiddle. I am getting my data from the server-side... so I need either a work around, or another approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternate way to the `checkbox` of hiding/displaying.

I use [Bootstrap 3 tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) to apply different filters:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs form-tabs" id="search-tabs">
    <li id="basic-list" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" data-dtname="all" href="#all">All</a></li>
    <li class="" id="dereg-list"> <a data-toggle="tab" data-dtname="dereg" href="#dereg">Deregistered</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<div class="tab-content">
    <fieldset id="all" class="tab-pane active">        
        <table id="agent_search" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <th>Agent ID</th>
                <th>Agent Name</th>
                <th>ID Number</th>
                <th>Mobile Number</th>
                <th>Team Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th></th>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="dereg" class="tab-pane ">
        <table id="dereg_agent_search" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <th>Agent ID</th>
                <th>Agent Name</th>
                <th>ID Number</th>
                <th>Mobile Number</th>
                <th>Team Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th></th>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

I first initialize the table on the first tab `all` which uses `bServerSide=true` and for the other table(when I switch to the other tab) I do:

```
$('#search-tabs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
    if (this.dataset["dtname"] == "all") {
        oTable.fnDraw();
    } else if (this.dataset["dtname"] == "dereg") {
        var data = $("form").serialize();
        $.post(
            url,  data
        ).success(function(data){
            console.log(data.aaData);
            kTable = $('#dereg_agent_search').dataTable( {
                "sScrollY": "250px",
                "data": data.aaData,

                "destroy" : true,
                "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'><'col-sm-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'>>S",
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                  { 
                        "bSortable": false, 
                        "aTargets": [ 6 ], 
                        "sWidth":"150px",
                        "mRender": function( data, type, full ){
                            return "<div class='btn-group'><a href="+full[6][0]+" class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>View</a><a href="+full[6][1]+" class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>Edit</a></div>"
                        }
                    },
                    { 
                        "bSortable": true, 
                        "aTargets": [ 0 ], 
                        "sWidth":"150px",
                        "mRender": function( data, type, full ){
                            if (full[5] == "DEACTIVATED"){
                                return "<a href="+full[6][0]+" class='DEACTIVATED'>"+data+"</a>"
                            } else{
                                return "<a href="+full[6][0]+">"+data+"</a>"

                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {"aTargets": [ 4 ], "sWidth":"250px" },
                    {"aTargets": [ 5 ], "bVisible":false},
                ],
                "bDeferRender": true,
                "bStateSave": true
            } );
        });
        kTable.fnDraw();
    }

});
```

Notice that I get the data to populate the table from the server - using a jQuery `$.post` request, and then I use datatables' `data` attribute to populate the table.

I hope This can Help someone.